# Bad execution plan on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to migrate from SQL Server to Postgresql.
Here is my Posgresql code:

```
Create View person_names As
SELECT lp."Code", n."Name", n."Type"
from "Persons" lp
Left Join LATERAL
(
    Select *
    From "Names" n
    Where n.id = lp.id
    Order By "Date" desc
    Limit 1
) n on true
limit 100;

Explain
Select "Code" From person_names;
```

It prints

```
"Subquery Scan on person_names  (cost=0.42..448.85 rows=100 width=10)"
"  ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..447.85 rows=100 width=56)"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.42..303946.91 rows=67931 width=56)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on ""Persons"" lp  (cost=0.00..1314.31 rows=67931 width=10)"
"              ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=100)"
"                    ->  Index Only Scan Backward using ""IX_Names_Person"" on ""Names"" n  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=100)"
"                          Index Cond: ("id" = (lp."id")::numeric)"
```

Why there is an "Index Only Scan" for the "Names" table? This table is not required to get a result. On SQL Server I get only a single scan over the "Persons" table.
How can I tune Postgres to get a better query plans? I'm trying the lastest version, which is the Postgresql 15 beta 3.

Here is SQL Server version:

```
Create View person_names As
SELECT top 100 lp."Code", n."Name", n."Type"
from "Persons" lp
Outer Apply
(
    Select Top 1 *
    From "Names" n
    Where n.id = lp.id
    Order By "Date" desc
) n
GO

SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON;
GO

Select "Code" From person_names;
```

It gives correct execution plan:

```
  |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((100)))
       |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([Persons].[IX_Persons] AS [lp]))
```

Comment: Try using a subquery instead of a lateral join

Comment: Of course the table "Names" is required to get a result. You are joining to it, and you are using a column from that table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought so as well at first, but OP is referring to `Select "Code" From person_names;` where they use the view. Given the LEFT JOIN returns at most one row, it doesn't change the result.

Comment: Such a great example of why MS can charge for SQL Server licenses even though there is a free Postgres available. Simple, short query. Brilliant. Give it to Postgres developers, maybe they could improve its optimizer in one of the next versions.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but why a LIMIT without an order by? That's essentially a random result each time you select from that view.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `limit 100` was in my test example. I don't use it in the real life.

Comment: Whenever you ask about SQL query optimization, **show the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Answer (score 3):

Change the lateral join to a regular left join, then Postgres is able to remove the select on the `Names` table:

```
create View person_names 
As
SELECT lp.Code, n.Name, n.Type
from Persons lp
  Left Join (
    Select distinct on (id) *
    From Names n
    Order By id, Date desc
  ) n on n.id = lp.id
limit 100;
```

The following index will support the `distinct on ()` in case you do include columns from the `Names` table:

```
create index on "Names"(id, "Date" desc);
```

For `select code from names` this gives me this plan:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on persons lp  (cost=0.00..309.00 rows=20000 width=7) (actual time=0.009..1.348 rows=20000 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.262 ms                                                                                     
Execution Time: 1.738 ms
```

For `select Code, name, type From person_names;` this gives me this plan:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hash Right Join  (cost=559.42..14465.93 rows=20000 width=25) (actual time=5.585..68.545 rows=20000 loops=1)                                          
  Hash Cond: (n.id = lp.id)                                                                                                                          
  ->  Unique  (cost=0.42..13653.49 rows=20074 width=26) (actual time=0.053..57.323 rows=20000 loops=1)                                               
        ->  Index Scan using names_id_date_idx on names n  (cost=0.42..12903.49 rows=300000 width=26) (actual time=0.052..41.125 rows=300000 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=309.00..309.00 rows=20000 width=11) (actual time=5.407..5.407 rows=20000 loops=1)                                                  
        Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1116kB                                                                                             
        ->  Seq Scan on persons lp  (cost=0.00..309.00 rows=20000 width=11) (actual time=0.011..2.036 rows=20000 loops=1)                            
Planning Time: 0.460 ms                                                                                                                              
Execution Time: 69.180 ms
```

Of course I had to guess the table structures as you haven't provided any DDL.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2a40ef028bb2d9bfef67db2dd30e9541)

Comment: Trying to do this way. 1st, I get "Names" in the execution plan, anyway. Not helped. 2nd, Plan shows a "Seq scan" on "Names" even I've created an index (id asc, Date desc), seems strange.

Comment: @Raider: for me the index gets used for the `distinct on` - however I had to guess the table definitions as you have not provided any DDL.

Comment: My fault. Sorry. I made an index `(id ASC NULLS LAST, Date DESC NULLS LAST)` (copy-pasted). Changed to `(id asc, Date desc)` it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Change your view definition like that

```
create view person_names as
select p."Code",
       (select "Name"
        from "Names" n
        where n.id = p.id
        order by "Date" desc
        limit 1)
from "Persons" p
limit 100;
```

Comment: Sometimes there are a lot of columns comes from a second table, not a single column. Your solution works only for a single column from a second table.

Comment: @Raider welp, there's no DDL in your question, and no specifics to what do you want to achieve exactly. This solution solves the problem you have in your question. As for more broad approach, I'd argue you should looking into schema changes rather than trying to trick query planner. If you want a more general solution, then please update your question